# Simple algebra help; shouldn't it be $-e^6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving a problem with a number of distrbution, and in counting the total distribution function, I have encountered a simple math error that I can not quite recall. need some explanation.
Why is:

$1 - [1 - e^{-0.5/0.25}] = e^{-6}$

Shouldn't it be $-e^6$?

Comment: $0.5/0.25=2$, not $6$.

Comment: Before you retype the formulas its hard to know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$1 - [1 - e^{-\frac{.5}{.25}}] =1-1+e^{-2}=e^{-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

No. $-(1-e^x) = -1+e^x$ as multiplication distributes over addition / subtraction.